# How to prevent changes in a cell based on another value and show an alert box about the attempt?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have column (col 3) which has a dropdown. One of the option is PENDING. In the next cell (col 4) is another drop-down, NOTSUBMITTED being one of the options.

Now what I want is that if Col 3 has PENDING, I should not be able to change the next cell in Col 4. In short, NOTSUBMITTED cannot be changed if Col 3 has PENDING.

Then show a POPUP message stating some information about this. I tried the following but it shows the message but I cannot stop the Col 4 being changed. I can easily change or deleted the Col 4.

How to stop this.

```
function onEdit(event){

      var actvCell = event.range.getSheet().getActiveCell();

     if(actvCell.getColumn() == 3 && event.value=="PENDING"){   
        Browser.msgBox('You cannot make changes if payment is pending');
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

You want to stop another cell from being edited depending on the value from active cell.

**Solution**

You need to take a look on how `Protection` class works for `Spreadsheet` Service. Algorithm is as follows:

1. If *active* cell value is "pending" -> protect *target* cell and remove users from protection editors;
2. If *active* cell value is other -> get protections and filter to leave one on *target* cell;
3. Remove protection from *target* cell.

Please, remember that there are a lot of considerations to take into account regarding editing permissions, most important ones are:

1. *Owner* of the spreadsheet can always edit everything regardless of protections;
2. *Domain-wide* permissions will still be in effect;
3. *Current user* (the one making the edit) can't be removed from editors;

**Useful links**

1. `Protection` class [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection);
2. `getProtections()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getProtections(ProtectionType));
3. `protect()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#protect);
4. `remove()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#remove);
5. `removeEditors()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#removeEditors(String));